# reset_mock() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_value' — why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

According to the [unittest.mock.reset_mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.reset_mock) documentation, `reset_mock` accepts `return_value` and `side_effect` keyword arguments.  But when I try to use it, I get a TypeError:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import pandas

def foo():
    return pandas.read_csv("/dev/null")

@patch("pandas.read_csv", autospec=True)
def test_foo(pr):
    pr.return_value = 42
    foo()
    pr.reset_mock(return_value=True)
    foo()
```

Running with with `pytest` gives:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /tmp
plugins: mock-1.12.1, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item

mwe17.py F                                                               [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_foo ___________________________________

pr = <function read_csv at 0x7fdeff5ddbf8>

    @patch("pandas.read_csv", autospec=True)
    def test_foo(pr):
        pr.return_value = 42
        foo()
>       pr.reset_mock(return_value=True)
E       TypeError: reset_mock() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_value'

mwe17.py:11: TypeError
============================== 1 failed in 2.83s ===============================
```

When I mock `os.mkdir` instead of `pandas.read_csv`, it does work.

Why does `reset_mock` when mocking one function fail to accept this keyword argument, but mocking another does?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `autospec=True` from `patch` call solves the issue for me.